# Big O Notation, adding loops of different significance

Tags: java, loops, big-o, nested-loops

I promise this is the last Big O question

Big O Notation for following loops...

```
     for (int i = n; i > 0; i = i / 2){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
           count++;
        }
     }
     for (int k = 0; k < n; k++){
        for (int m = 0; m < n; m++){
           count++;
        }
     }
```

here is what i think im sure of.

the first set of nested loops has `O(n*log2(n))`  and the second set of nested loops is `O(n^2)`.  When adding these is it correct to drop the first term? and say that the overall Big O is `O(n^2)`?

Second question, when adding Big O notation for loops in series is always correct to drop the less significant terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to both your questions is yes. You always drop smaller terms, as they are dominated by the larger terms for sufficiently large `n`, and you only care about large `n` when doing Big O analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `n*log2(n)` is *dominated by* `n^2` asymptotically: for sufficiently large `n`, `|n * log2(n)| < |n^2|`.

If you don't see why this means you can drop the `n*log2(n)` term, try adding `n^2` to both sides:

```
n^2 + n*log2(n) < n^2 + n^2
n^2 + n*log2(n) < 2 * n^2
```

Thus, if we know that we can ignore a constant factor `k`, we know we can ignore a less significant term.,